# Python : Check specific key in nested dictionary and return all previous keys if its matched

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a nested dictionary and i want to iterated whole dictionary to check for specific key. If its matched I want to return all keys which I iterated over to reach that specific key.

```
My Dictionary:

d = {
    "aaa":{
        "bbb":"xyz",
        "ccc":{
            "description":"xyz",
            "data":"abc"
        }
        "description":"xyz"
    }
    "xxx":{
        "description":"xyz",
        "bbb":{
            "ccc":{
                "ddd":{
                    "description":"xyz"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Excpected output:

aaa--description
aaa--ccc--description
xxx--description
xxx--bbb--ccc--ddd--description
```

I tried the below code but am not getting expected output

```
tmp_str = ""
def iter_dict(d):
    global tmp_str
    for key in sorted(d.keys()):
        if type(d[key]) == dict and len(d[key]) > 0:
            tmp_str += "--%s" %key
            iter_dict(d[key])
        elif key == "description":
            tmp_str += "--%s\n" %(key)

for key in d.keys():
    tmp_str += "\n\n%s" %key
    iter_dict(d[key])
print tmp_str
```

Please share your ideas.. thanks

Comment: Before I share a solution I want to make sure you are aware that dictionaries are not ordered. Whenever you run this code it would yield different outputs because the keys you iterated over before the correct one would be different each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the keys you have seen when recursing. Just add a parameter to your `iter_dict` function and push/pop the keys there.

Also: do not use this global `tmp_str`, just return the value.

```
def iter_dict(d, rec_keys=None):
    rec_keys = rec_keys or []
    results = []
    for key, value in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
        if isinstance(value, dict) and value:
            results.append(iter_dict(value, rec_keys + [key]))
        elif key == "description":
            results.append('--'.join(rec_keys + ['description']))
    return '\n'.join(results)

tmp_str = iter_dict(d)
```

This results in:

```
>>> print(tmp_str)
aaa--ccc--description
aaa--description
xxx--bbb--ccc--ddd--description
xxx--description
```

I'll leave the ordering of the lines to you as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it with a recursive generator:

```
d = {
    "aaa":{
        "bbb":"xyz",
        "ccc":{
            "description":"xyz",
            "data":"abc"
        },
        "description":"xyz"
    },
    "xxx":{
        "description":"xyz",
        "bbb":{
            "ccc":{
                "ddd":{
                    "description":"xyz"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


def paths_to_key(key, d, current_path=None):
    if current_path is None:
        current_path = []

    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == key:
            yield current_path + [key]
        else:
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                path = current_path + [k]
                yield from paths_to_key(key, v, path)

for path in paths_to_key('description', d):
    print(path)
```

Output:

```
['xxx', 'description']
['xxx', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'description']
['aaa', 'ccc', 'description']
['aaa', 'description']
```